# `URDF/COLLADA file is not a valid robot model` error when using moveit_setup_assistant

Tags: moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

I am using ros2 humble and i want to configure my ur5 with moveit for that in my terminal i used this command:

```
ros2 launch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch.py
```

which will open moveit setup assistant when i click to create new moveit configuration package and add ur.urdf.xacron i.e available in urdf file of ur_ros_driver. I am getting this error in my terminal

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/2023-11-24-23-19-50-322943-ubuntu-Inspiron-N5010-4417
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [moveit_setup_assistant-1]: process started with pid [4419]
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] error: Undefined substitution argument name
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] when processing file: /home/ubuntu/workspace/ros_ur_driver/src/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ur_moveit_config/srdf/ur.srdf.xacro
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] Error:   Error document empty.
[moveit_setup_assistant-1]          at line 100 in ./urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] Failed to parse robot description using: urdf_xml_parser/URDFXMLParser
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[moveit_setup_assistant-1]   what():  URDF/COLLADA file is not a valid robot model.
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #31   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2d6c712, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #30   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2dcbfd4, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #29   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2dc8d3f, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #28   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2d72e46, in QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool, bool)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #27   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b20b9e39, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #26   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2d74363, in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #25   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2d6c712, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #24   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2daf4ed, in QWidget::event(QEvent*)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #23   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2e641e6, in QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #22   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2e63fc3, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #21   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2e6239d, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #20   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2e62115, in QAbstractButton::clicked(bool)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #19   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b20f17c7, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #18   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libmoveit_setup_framework.so", at 0x7f44b38ab50f, in moveit_setup::LoadPathWidget::btnFileDialog()
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #17   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2ec2a91, in QWidgetLineControl::internalSetText(QString const&, int, bool)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #16   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2ec27ce, in QWidgetLineControl::finishChange(int, bool, bool)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #15   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2ebf0f8, in QWidgetLineControl::textChanged(QString const&)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #14   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b20f17c7, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #13   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b2eb7845, in QLineEdit::textChanged(QString const&)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #12   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b20f17c7, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #11   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libmoveit_setup_framework.so", at 0x7f44b38d4315, in moveit_setup::LoadPathWidget::pathChanged(QString const&)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #10   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.15.3", at 0x7f44b20f17c7, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #9    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libmoveit_setup_core_plugins.so", at 0x7f4494958e89, in moveit_setup::core::StartScreenWidget::onUrdfPathChanged(QString const&)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #8    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libmoveit_setup_core_plugins.so", at 0x7f4494957060, in moveit_setup::core::StartScreen::loadURDFFile(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #7    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libmoveit_setup_framework.so", at 0x7f44b38a3a6e, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f44b1aae4d7, in __cxa_throw
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f44b1aae276, in std::terminate()
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f44b1aae20b, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f44b1aa2b9d, in 
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7f44b16287f2]
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7f44b1642475]
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[moveit_setup_assistant-1]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[moveit_setup_assistant-1]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7f44b16969fc]
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 4419 1000)
[ERROR] [moveit_setup_assistant-1]: process has died [pid 4419, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant --ros-args'].
```

Any clue what could be the problem here?

Thank you in advance